# Guessing the average of the class

Tags: reference-request, game-theory

I am sorry if the title is not clear enough. I came across this question yesterday but I don't know how to give a title to it. It would be nice if you can (i) give me some ideas of solving the question and (ii) direct me to the related field in mathematics, as I would like to know more about this topic.

> Suppose there are $30$ students in a class. Each student receives a
>   piece of paper and they are asked to write down a rational number
>   between $0$ and $100$ inclusively without talking to others. The teacher then collects the
>   papers. She would find the average of the $30$ numbers and multiply
>   the average by $0.7$. Denote $x$ as the final product. Five students
>   with their numbers closest to $x$ will receive a prize. If you are one
>   of the students aiming for the prize, what number should you write down?

I believe that it is related to game theory, but I am not sure. Please kindly shed some lights for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would try it with smaller numbers (fewer than 30 students, fewer students getting prizes) where you might be able to do an exhaustive analysis to get some idea of what to expect in the full case.

Comment: @GerryMyerson : Thank you for the reply. May I ask why the number of students getting prize is an important factor to consider?

Comment: If you can solve the problem with five students getting prizes, go ahead. If you can't, try to solve it with just one student getting a prize. It might be easier, and might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty well known "paradox", you can find pretty good description [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guess_2/3_of_the_average). In your case the average is multiplied by $0.7$ instead of $\frac{2}{3}$, but it doesn't change the conclusion.

Basically, if all students were acting perfectly rationally they would all write $0$. The argument goes a little bit like this: choosing any number over $0.7$ (in your case) is irrational, as for sure the "target" will not be that high (even if everyone wrote 100). But if no-one will choose a number higher than $0.7$ then the target will not exceed $0.49$ (even if everyone wrote $0.7$). By that logic you can show that it is not rational to write any number over $0$. Of course in real world we don't observe such extreme reasoning, with most people

If you wish to investigate the matter further, [here](http://www.emiliocuilty.com/uploads/4/1/5/0/4150845/unraveling_in_guessing_games.pdf) is a pretty good paper.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Seems that the best strategy depends on how rational the other classmates are.

Comment: In practice yes. The paper I linked deals with exactly that, I recommend you read it if you haven't yet, it's pretty short.